# Can I get to iTunes Match library from more than one Mac?

Tags: itunes-match

My home machine, where the bulk of my music library lives, is currently syncing itself up to iTunes Match. It's a big library and a long process, and the upstream on my cable modem is tragically slow, so it's taking it a couple days to fully do. I can see on my iPhone and my iPad the status of that, and can pull my music down to my devices from the cloud, and so far it's pretty great.

My Mac at work has a smaller subset of my full library on it (pulled out of my iPhone with [Senuti](http://www.fadingred.com/senuti/)). What I want is for it to share and download from my iTunes Match account, like my iOS devices do. When I turn on iTunes Match on my work computer, it does its "gathering information" step, and then when it goes to "match your music", it tells me another computer is syncing (which it is) and it can't do two at once.

So does that imply that when my home machine finally gets done (probably today), I can do the same process on my work machine, and the two accounts and libraries will be synched up with the cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add the second Mac once the first has completed. While one is currently uploading, I think the others can only be linked and start viewing.

Comment: Sorry, should have said... The thing is, my second one ISN'T linked. It's got all its own local content, and the iCloud Status on each song is "waiting". My iOS devices are clearly linked, and can even see listings that aren't uploaded yet (they're greyed out). My second mac can't see the cloud library at all.

Comment: Are you using the same Apple ID on both?